# get FileSystemEventArgs in class

Tags: c#

this class

```
class Class1
{
    public void onChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e, StreamWriter file)
    {
        file.WriteLine("Changed: " + e.FullPath);
        file.AutoFlush = true;
}
```

i call it in this code

```
Class1 Cl = new Class1();
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler( Cl.onChanged( ? ) );
```

but I do not know how to pass " object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e, StreamWriter file " into class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would strongly suggest reading up on [events and delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx); even if you use the answer provided, you'll probably won't get far without understanding the concept.

In you scenario you can't pass the `StreamWriter` reference to your event-handling method - it must match the signature of `FileSystemEventHandler` exactly. You could try something as follows:

```
class Class1
{
    public StreamWriter file;

    public Class1(StreamWriter file)
    {
       this.file = file;
    }

    public void onChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        file.WriteLine("Changed: " + e.FullPath);
        file.AutoFlush = true;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
Class1 Cl = new Class1(someStreamWriterInstantiatedPreviously);
System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Changed += Cl.onChanged;
```

Note that this is a simplified implementation - depending on your logic, you might consider implementing `IDisposable` with your `Class1` to ensure the file stream is properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass parameters when you attaching an event handler,just specify the method name:

```
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(Cl.onChanged);
```

But I suspect it's not gonna work like this, try to make your method static,or define your method inside of your current class.(the class that you define your `FileSystemWatcher` in it)

By the way your method signature doesn't match with the `FileSystemEventHandler` delegate:

```
public delegate void FileSystemEventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e);
```

You should change your method signature.Delete the `StreamWriter` parameter.

Also that line can be written with short notation like this:

```
watcher.Changed += Cl.onChanged;
```